# Best way to store list with custom order

Tags: sql, list, sql-order-by

My use case is that each user has a list of images. They can perform all crud operations and **set a custom order for the list**, my idea is users could drag the images and sort them.

My question is, what is the best way to store the structure of the images for accomplish this goal?

The only idea I have is to set a field named "order" like:

| id | path | order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | foo | 10 |
| 2 | bar | 20 |
| 3 | bob | 30 |

The select query will end always with "ORDER BY order"

But every time the user insert a new image between other two I will have to find a order number between, and if they are close together I will have to manipulate the fields.

I feel that this logic is a bit a mess...

Imagine an extreme situation:

I have the image foo in order 10 and the image bar in order 20.
Now I insert 100 images and place all these images between the foo and bar images.

I can place 9 images in between, but then I must increase the bar order every time I place another image in bewteen...

Is there a more 'elegant' way to solve this problem?

Comment: What is wrong ordering using the `id` auto increment column?  Or could you possibly use a timestamp column?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, OP deals with the problem when the user changes image order, e.g. suddenly wants image ordered 45 to instead be placed between 240 and 250.

Comment: You could have bigger steps, e.g. 1000. But you will still have to take care of the no-gap problem, if it occurs.

Comment: @jarlh Yes I know... but I was trying to find another way... (maybe there isn't) I mean this is a recurring problem, a lot of developers should be dealt with it. Can exist some pattern to solve it?

Comment: You can use a char string. When you need to add 100 row between '11' and '12' it could be assigned order='1100'..'1199'. A bit tricky method to compute  new orders but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution may not be so elegant, but you're not alone: at least one major ERP system adopt a very similar approach.

Their strategy in detail is:

- when you add a row at the end, assign the `order` of the previous row plus a fixed value `N` (usually 10000: I don't know why they didn't choose a power of 2)
- when you need to insert a row between other two, assign the average of the `order`s of those two rows (i.e. split the gap evenly)
- have a housekeeping procedure that restores a gap of `N` between all rows. This procedure may be scheduled for periodic execution, and will be called "in emergency" when you need to do an insertion and you only have a gap of 1

Please note, the number of insertion you can perform without renumbering is `log2(N)`. If you foresee the possibility of bulk inserts as in your example, you will need to:

- implement the housekeeping procedure in such a way that it creates a large enough gap at the point of insertion, e.g. not `N` but `N*M`, where `M` is the number of rows to insert
- modify the insertion algorithm to make the best possible use of the available space: if you are inserting 20 rows between 10000 and 210000, the above algorithm would set the first inserted row at 110000, the second at 160000, etc; you want instead the first at 20000, the second at 30000, etc.